# Unchecking certain checkboxes returned by a jQuery class selector

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to uncheck a certain number of ASP checkboxes (of class "chkInline") via jQuery. I have six checkboxes, and want to loop through them to uncheck all those between indexes 2 and 5 inclusive. I have tried:

```
var checkBoxes = $(".chkInline");
for (var i = 2; i < 6; i++) {
        checkBoxes.eq(i).prop("checked", false);
    }
```

But this does nothing. Am I accessing the correct object here? I can add and remove classes using a similar method, it just seems that no properties of the checkbox can be accessed this way.

Comment: You logic looks syntatically valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery all the way

If it does not work for you, ASP has possibly changed your class - view-source to see  - alternatively use `$("input[type=checkbox]")` as you mention in your comment

```js
$(".chkInline").each(function(i) {
  if (i >= 2 && i < 6) $(this).prop("checked", false)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" checked class="chkInline" />
<input type="checkbox" checked class="chkInline" />
<input type="checkbox" checked class="chkInline" />
<input type="checkbox" checked class="chkInline" />
<input type="checkbox" checked class="chkInline" />
<input type="checkbox" checked class="chkInline" />
<input type="checkbox" checked class="chkInline" />
```

Comment: You could also potentially just `$('.chkInline').slice(2, 5).prop('checked', false);`

Comment: Thanks - you were right. It looks like the class was being changed, so I selected on $("input[type=checkbox]") instead, which works nicely. Good call on the use of slice too!